# Отследить закрытие страницы

Tags: javascript, java, spring, websocket

Возможен ли способ проверки пребывания пользователя на странице через spring-WebSocket, sockJS?

Или нужно свой скрипт писать в js, например каждые 10 сек отправлять запрос серверу.

Я просто хочу сделать статус участникам беседы моего чата, но не знаю как лучше это реализовать, подскажите пожалуйста варианты...

Comment: Ну так если пользователь подключен к `websocket`-у - значит на странице. Если не подключен, значит не на странице.

Comment: Как это проверить? socket.onclose подойдет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

а почему не воспользоваться window.onbeforeunload? Если пользователь пытается закрыть вкладку, отправлять данные на сервер и менять ему статус

Comment: Пробовал, но мне не нравится всплывающее окошко. Можно его убрать?

Comment: Да, я так делал, правда очень давно. Не обязательно должно быть окно. Можно сделать что-то типа: window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) { ajax отправка}

Comment: Только что попробовал на кастомном шаблоне в body запихать onbeforeunload="return myFunction()". Вроде окошко не влазит. Сейчас гляну как оно вместе с сервером робит.

Comment: Действительно робит!